# How to add a line to the Text property of a textbox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

I have `TextBox` in a Windows form application. And I write a text in it.

eg.

```
texbox.Text = " first line ";
....
textbox.Text = "second line";
```

When I write second text, the first line is deleted. How to leave the first line and write next texts in next line in the `TextBox`?

I want the following result:

```
first line
second line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
textbox.text = "first line";
textbox.text += "\nsecond line";
```

or

```
textbox.text = "first line";
textbox.text = textbox.text + "\nsecond line";
```

Comment: I don't now why `\n` doesn't work... But I solve problem using `Environment.NewLine`

Answer (score 1):

You want to change the `TextMode` property to `MultiLine`

then you can write like

```
texbox.text = " first line ";
....
textbox.text += "\nsecond line";
```

Please note the append operator `+=` and `\n` which is new line character

Answer (score 1):

I usually write a wrapper.

One important difference is to use

```
Environment.Newline
```

instead of

```
"\n\r".
```

Also, as others have noted, set the textBox multiline property.

```
    public void WriteLine(string msg)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
        {
            msg = string.Format("{0}{1}", Environment.NewLine, msg);
        }
        textBox.AppendText(msg);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Textbox `multiline` property to true and can use `\r\n` for multiline text like below:

```
TextBox1.Text = "First line\r\nSecond line";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do following ways also.

textbox.text = "first line";
textbox.text = textbox.text + vbCrlf + "second line";

Comment: This is a C# question, no VB!

Comment: textBox1.Text="First Line" + Environment.NewLine + "Second Line";         you can do this also and it will works fine in C# code.